# Como organizar datas no ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, r

Tenho um gráfico feito com `ggplot2`, mas na hora de exportá-lo, as datas no eixo X saem totalmente ilegíveis, como nesse exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso arrumá-las? Código que estou usando:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(reshape2)
  library(patchwork)
  library(gghighlight)
  library(zoo)
})

#### Import data ####

url <- httr::GET("https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalGeral",
                 httr::add_headers("X-Parse-Application-Id" =
                                     "unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm")) %>%
  httr::content() %>%
  '[['("results") %>%
  '[['(1) %>%
  '[['("arquivo") %>%
  '[['("url")

dados <- utils::read.csv2(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding = "latin1")
dados$data <- lubridate::as_date(dados$data)

dados <- dados %>%
  filter(data > as.Date("2020-02-29"))

rm(url)

dados %>%
  mutate(mm7dCasos = rollmean(casosNovos, 7, fill = list(NA, NULL, NA), align = "right")) %>%
  filter(data > "2020-03-14") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = casosNovos), na.rm = TRUE, color = "black", fill = "#ADD8E6") +
  geom_line(aes(x =data, y = mm7dCasos), color = "#FF6347", size = 0.75) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  ggtitle("Variação diária de novos casos confirmados - Brasil", "(MM7d)") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 500)) +
  facet_wrap(~estado, nrow = 3)
```

Comment: Não consegui compreender como funciona o ```scale_x_date```.

Comment: Tente `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `scale_x_date` ou alterar o ângulo das datas.

Usando o `scale_x_date`:

```
scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "2 week")
```

Alterando o ângulo das datas (neste caso, em 45˚ graus):

```
theme(text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Código novo:

```
dados %>%
  mutate(mm7dCasos = rollmean(casosNovos, 7, fill = list(NA, NULL, NA), align = "right")) %>%
  filter(data > "2020-03-14") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = casosNovos), na.rm = TRUE, color = "black", fill = "#ADD8E6") +
  geom_line(aes(x =data, y = mm7dCasos), color = "#FF6347", size = 0.75) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  ggtitle("Variação diária de novos casos confirmados - Brasil", "(MM7d)") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 500)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "2 week") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~estado, nrow = 3)
```